# Replace '$' using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

I want to replace

! = change

@ = static(does not)

$ =  Want to replace

I got a string like this @!$!
How do I replace the $ with something else?

**EDIT: I need to use Regex as the string may appear anywhere!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace method.

```
Regex.Replace("@!$!", "!(.*)!", "replacement value");
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a regular expression, just use the [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) method:

```
String result = input.Replace("$", "somethingElse");
```

---

**As a side note**: The way that you would do this with a regular expression would be like this:

```
String result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\$", "somethingElse");
```

Notice that I have escaped the `$` with a backslash since `$` usually means *match the end of the string*.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want some RegExp for string replacement. You can just use string.Replace() fundtion.

Answer (score 0):

also, check out [Rubular](http://rubular.com/), a great RegEx Tester.

Answer (score -1):

Using the String class' .Replace() method would do the trick but, if you really want to use RegEx, this is a great RegEx site that I use quite often.

[Regular Expression Library](http://regexlib.com/Default.aspx)

You should be able to find what you're looking for there.

Comment: The OP has asked how to build a house, and you have given him the address to a hardware store.

Comment: I'm assuming that this guy get paid for what he dose and I thought it better to give him the tools he needs to accomplish his job instead of doing his job for him and giving him the answer. Sort of the "Give a man a fish, feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, feed him for a lifetime." approach. I suppose I could have ALSO given him the answer.